# ase.visualize.view misses pygtk

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.5

On Ubuntu 16.04 machinge w/ XFCE desktop i have installed `python3` and `pip` with the command `sudo apt install python3-pip`. I then installed `numpy` and `ase` (atomic Simulation Environment) using `sudo -H python3 -m pip install --upgrade numpy ase`. No apparent problems. However, running this `mwe.m`:

```
from ase import Atoms
from ase.build import fcc111

slab = fcc111('Cu', size=(4, 4, 2), vacuum=10.0)

from ase.visualize import view
view(slab)
```

results in the following:

```
$ python3 mwe.m
$ ImportError: No module named 'pygtk'
To get a full traceback, use: ase-gui --verbose
```

The problem is in the `view` command that depends on `ase-gui` which seem to depend on `pygtk`.
My goal is to go through [this tutorial](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/tutorials/surface.html). Of course I'm a novice, any help is appreciated. How can i overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none of the ASE gui functions will work with Python3. PyGTK is only for Python2 and it has been moved to [PyGObject](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/PyGObject?action=show&redirect=PyGObject) for Python3. This is an [open issue](https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/issues/13) for the ASE team. Your best bet right now is to use ASE with Python2.